# Enable ag-grid group footer only for certain groups

Tags: angular, grid, grouping, footer, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with angular2 and have a grid with 2 row groupings, where 1 row grouping is included in the other one.
Here is an example of what I have:
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcNBS.png)
 and here is my grid configuration:

```
    gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    api: null,
    pivotMode: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    suppressAggFuncInHeader: true,
    groupUseEntireRow: false,
    groupIncludeFooter: true
    groupColumnDef: {
        cellRenderer: 'group',
        cellRendererParams: {
            suppressCount: true,
            footerValueGetter: '"Footer row name"'
        },
        headerName: 'Groups column name'
    }
};

columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {headerName: 'Highest level row group', field: 'a', rowGroupIndex: 0},
    {headerName: 'Second level row group', field: 'b', rowGroupIndex: 1},
    {headerName: 'cName', field: 'c', pivotIndex: 1},
    {headerName: 'dName', field: 'd', aggFunc: 'sum'}
];
```

Actually what I want is to be able to set the footer only for the highest level groups, so that my second level row grouping(rowGroupIndex = 1) will not have any footer rows. Another option I was thinking about is to disable row expansion for the second level rows (at the moment they are expanded on double click).

Does anybody knows if ag-grid has such functionality?

**UPD** I've found the [following answer](https://ag-grid.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=3977&pid=9614#pid9614) on ag-grid forum from one of the ag-grid devs:

> "can the grouping footer only be rendered at certain group level
>   instead of all levels?"
>   => no - it's all groups or none i'm afraid.

So the question is how to disable row expansion in ag-grid?

Thanks,
Andrey

Comment: I know this is an old question, but were you able to find a solution to this?